# Filtering items before adding to an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, filter

I'm just getting to grips with some c# after being thrown in at the deep end on a little scripting task.

I'm trying to amend some code that builds a drop-down box on a web page so that it contains a list of only four items, I'm not sure of the syntax required to achieve this but hoping you folks can help.

```
        using (CoreBusinessLayerProxy proxy = CoreBusinessLayerProxy.CreateCoreBusinessLayerProxy(BusinessLayerExceptionHandler))
        {
            eventTypesTable = proxy.GetEventTypesTable();
        }
        eventTypes.Items.Add(new ListItem(Resources.CoreWebContent.WEBCODE_VB0_201, "All events"));
        EventTypes.Add("All events", 0);
        foreach (DataRow r in eventTypesTable.Rows)
        {
            eventTypes.Items.Add(r["Name"].ToString());
            try
            {
                EventTypes.Add(r["Name"].ToString(), Int32.Parse(r["EventType"].ToString()));
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

I'm trying to amend the above so that rather than adding all of the `DataRow`'s from `eventTypeTable.Rows` it adds only a set of four hard-coded values which I suspect I need to pass during the `foreach` but I cannot for the life of me wrap my head around where or when I should be doing this in the loop.

(The joys of working on uncommented code)

Thanks!

Comment: So `eventTypesTable ` is a `DataTable`, `eventTypes` is the `DropDownList`(?) and `EventTypes` is ... what? Btw, **never** do `catch { }.`

Comment: _"it adds only a set of four hard-coded values"_ But i thought that this is desired because _"so that it contains a list of only four items"_. Sorry but the question is rather unclear.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, I'm wrapping my head around all this myself.
I'll attempt the solution below and see if that works otherwise I'll do my best to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rudimentary way to do this based on the Name field. If the Name is not one of "allow1", "allow2", "allow3" or "allow4", then it will `continue`. This moves to the next iteration in the foreach loop without executing the rest of the statement block for the current one.

```
    foreach (DataRow r in eventTypesTable.Rows)
    {
        string name = r["Name"].ToString();         
        if ( name != "allow1" && name != "allow2" && name != "allow3" && name != "allow4" )
            continue;

        eventTypes.Items.Add(r["Name"].ToString());
        try
        {
            EventTypes.Add(r["Name"].ToString(), Int32.Parse(r["EventType"].ToString()));
        }
        catch { }
    }
```